# Image rendered size exceeds max-width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive img tag:

```
<img width='800' height='600' srcset='img-400px.jpg 400w, img-700px.jpg 700w, img-1000px.jpg 1000w' sizes='(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, (max-width: 1840px) 63vw, 1200px' src='img.jpg'>
```

And CSS rules:

```
object-fit: contain;
width: auto;
margin: auto;
height: auto;
max-height: 900px;
max-width: 100%;
```

Even though the original image width is 800px and I have the rule `max-width: 100%` the browser renders the image wider than 800px. If I remove `width: auto`, the rendered size is correct (max 800px). Why does `width: auto` change the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I figured to understand what is the issue.

The browser does not override the `max-width` setting. When I use `img` with `sizes` attribute together with css rule `width: auto`, the browser uses `sizes` to allocate space for the image. This space can be wider than the image's real width. When I remove `width: auto` rule, the browser takes the width information from img's width attribute and the image can't exceed its intrinsic dimension. So the solution was to remove `width: auto` rule.